# [r package]Create sub folder in R

Tags: r, package

There are many R files in R/ in developing my package, so I want to move some files into sub folder(ex:  R/example/)
This process doesn't work successfully.
Could you tell me how to setup?
Or Should I have to make new my package and move some files into that?

Comment: You can't. If you want R code to be present in a package, it has to reside in a file in directory `R/`.  Not a subdirectory of it.